# Spinner setting ArrayList<String> as values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm working on a `spinner` and what I'm trying to achieve is set the `Arraylist` as the values for the selected item on the `spinner` but what I'm getting is the `arrayList` is the one being displayed as choices under `spinner`.

This is how I do it :

```
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.numSpinner);
    ArrayList<String> numArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    numArr.add("09054802841");
    numArr.add("09123456789");
    ArrayAdapter<String> numAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, numArr);
    spinner.setAdapter(numAdapter);
```

and this is how I get the value from the `spinner` and this is where I know the error occurs because **`Recipient_value_array`** is the values I get when I select an Item on the `spinner` where It should be the `Arraylist` values. How do I set It properly?

```
 itemSpin = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.recipient_value_array)[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of `Spinner` add a `setOnItemSelectedListener`

like:

```
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.numSpinner);
    final ArrayList<String> numArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    numArr.add("09054802841");
    numArr.add("09123456789");
    ArrayAdapter<String> numAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, numArr);
    spinner.setAdapter(numAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String value = numArr.get(i);
            Log.i("MainActivity", "Response: " + value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```